# Event Handler Not Firing From Foreach Loop

Tags: c#, winforms, events

```
        private string _orderUrl;

        IEnumerable<NotificationMessage> notificationMessages = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<NotificationMessage>>(response);

        foreach (var notificationMessage in notificationMessages)
        {
            bool success = notificationMessage.Success;
            string type = notificationMessage.Type;
            string message = notificationMessage.Message;
            _orderUrl = notificationMessage.OrderUrl;

            if (success)
            {
                _notifyIcon.BalloonTipTitle = BalloonTitle;
                _notifyIcon.BalloonTipText = type + @": " + message;
                _notifyIcon.BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Info;
                _notifyIcon.BalloonTipClicked += BalloonTip_Click;
                _notifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(10000);

                SystemSounds.Exclamation.Play();

                Thread.Sleep(10000);
            }
        }
    }

    void BalloonTip_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string urlBase = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UrlBase"];
        string target = urlBase + _orderUrl;
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(target);
    }
```

The loop displays a balloon notification in every 10 seconds. The idea is to click on the balloon to access the browser URL.

I have two questions. Can I fire the Click event for each balloon from outside the loop? Will the _orderUrl parameter be passed to the event handler?

Right now, the Click event is not firing.

Comment: You should use a timer instead of Thread.Sleep. You are currently locking up the UI thread, which is why the click event is not firing (it runs on the UI thread).

Comment: Have you tried using two different threads? That Sleep call looks suspicious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't ever use Thread.Sleep on a UI thread, it will lockup and your app will become unresponsive.

```
// This needs to be a class variable (not local)
private Queue<NotificationMessage> notificationMessages = new Queue<NotificationMessage>();


void LoadMessages()
{
    private string _orderUrl;
    this.notificationMessages = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<NotificationMessage>>(response);

   ShowNextMessage();
}

void ShowNextMessage()
{
    if (notificationMessages.Count == 0) return;
    var notificationMessage = notificationMessages.Dequeue();

    bool success = notificationMessage.Success;
    string type = notificationMessage.Type;
    string message = notificationMessage.Message;
    _orderUrl = notificationMessage.OrderUrl;

    if (success)
    {
        _notifyIcon.BalloonTipTitle = BalloonTitle;
        _notifyIcon.BalloonTipText = type + @": " + message;
        _notifyIcon.BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Info;
        _notifyIcon.BalloonTipClicked += BalloonTip_Click;
        _notifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(10000);

        SystemSounds.Exclamation.Play();
    }
}

void BalloonTip_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string urlBase = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UrlBase"];
    string target = urlBase + _orderUrl;
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(target);

    ShowNextMessage();
}
```